# Deriving properties of the logarithm from its integral representation

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Suppose we define:

$$\ln(x) = \int_{a}^{x} \left[ \frac{1}{r} dr\right]$$
Such that

$$ \ln(1) = 0, \ln(e) = 1$$

How does one derive all the properties of the logarithm from the properties of the function $$ \frac{1}{x}$$

For example:

If we let $x,y$ be functions of t. Then it follows that

$$ \frac{1}{x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{xy} \left( y \frac{dx}{dt} + x \frac{dy}{dt} \right) $$

Thus

$$ \ln(x(t)) + \ln(y(t)) = \ln(x(t)y(t)) $$

Arriving at the above statement was artificial. I first assumed the latter property true and then differentiated to find what initial algebraic identitiy had to exist. Is there a more natural motivation for this?

Comment: Do you mean $1$ instead of $a$ in $\int_a^x$?

Comment: I meant a to keep it general, i think that a  = 1 is implied from the initial conditions i specified

Comment: Well, showing the condition that $\ln e=1$ depends on the definition of $e$.

Comment: The lower limit should be $a=1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah ure rite, as I haven't yet defined e.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to prove that product formula:

$$\log(ax)=\int_{1}^{ax} \frac{dt}{t} =\int_{1}^x \frac{dt}{t} + \int_{x}^{ax} \frac{dt}{t} = \log(x) + \int_{x}^{ax} \frac{dt}{t}$$

Substituting $t=xu$, we get $$\int_{x}^{ax} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_{1}^{a}\frac{du}{u}=\log(a)$$

By induction from here, you can show $\log(x^n)=n\log(x)$.

If you define $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, then:

$$\log(e) =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{1/n}$$

The right hand is (essentially) the definition of the deivative of $\log(x)$ at $x=1$, so the limit is $\frac{1}{1}$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: I'm trying to follow step $t = xu$ , why does that make the integration limits (1,a)?

Comment: Because as $t$ goes from $x$ to $xa$, $u$ goes from $1$ to $a$, by standard substitution rules. @frogeyedpeas

Answer (score 3):

Define a function $f$ as

$$f(x) = \int_1^{x} \frac{1}{t} \,dt$$

for $x>0$.  It is easy to see show the following properties.

---

**Property (1):**  The function $f$ is increasing.

To show this, assume $x_2>x_1>0$, and form the difference $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{1}{t}\,dt$.  Note that this difference is strictly positive since the integrand is also strictly positive. Thus, $f(x_2)>f(x_1)$ whenever $x_2>x_1$, which implies $f$ is strictly increasing.

---

**Property (2):**
The function $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

This follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Note that this implies automatically that $f$ is continuous for $x>0$.

---

**Property (3):**
The limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=+\infty$

We can easily verify that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=+\infty$ since for $n>1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{2^n} \frac{1}{t} dt&=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{t} \,dt+\int_{2}^{4} \frac{1}{t} dt+\cdots +\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}} \frac{1}{t} \,dt\\\\
&\ge \int_{1}^{2} \frac{1}{2} \,dt+\int_{2}^{4} \frac{1}{4} \,dt+\cdots +\int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}} \frac{1}{2^n} \,dt\\\\
&=\frac12 (2-1)+\frac14 (4-2) + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{n}}(2^n-2^{n-1})\\\\
&=\frac{n}{2}
\end{align}$$

which tends to infinity as $n \to \infty$.

---

**Property (4):**
The limit $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)=-\infty$

Examine the integral

$$f(\frac{1}{n})=-\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 \frac{1}{t}\,dt$$
and substitute $u=\frac{1}{t}$.  Then, we have
$$-\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^1 \frac{1}{t}\,dt=-\int_1^n \frac{1}{u}\,du$$

But from property (3), this integral tends to $+\infty$ and thus $f(\frac1{n})$ tends to $-\infty$ as $n \to 0$.

---

**Property (5):**
The function $f$ satisfies $f(x^n) = nf(x)$.

We know by definition that
$$f(x^n) = \int_1^{x^n} \frac{1}{t} \,dt$$

Then, by substituting $t=u^n$, with $dt=nu^{n-1}du$, and the limits going from $1$ to $x$ reveals
$$\begin{align}
\log (x^n)  &=\int_1^{x} \frac{nu^{n-1}}{u^n} \,du\\\\
&=\int_1^{x} n\frac{1}u\,du\\\\
&=nf (x)
\end{align}$$

---

> The other well-known properties for the log of a product and quotient follow from Property (5).  For example, in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176741/prove-that-fxy-fx-fy-when-fx-is-not-lnx/2176760#2176760), I show that $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$.