# Prove that F(x + y ) = F(x)*F(y) | F(-x) = 1/F(x) | F(x)^n = F(nx) | F(n) = e^n

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-function

I am currently trying to get a deeper understanding of the properties of inverse functions and integrals, so I would very much appreciate it if you could give me a little hand. This is a collection of some tasks I was unable to entirely grasp on my own.

Some background information:
F(x) is the inverse function of
$$G(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$$ for x > 0.

I have proven that both F(x) and G(x) are continuous and differentiable. 
$$V_F = [0, \infty]\wedge D_F = R$$

We know that G(e) = 1, and therefore F(1) = e.

The issue here is proving:

$$F(a + b) = F(a)*F(b)$$
$$F(-a) = \frac{1}{F(a)}$$
$$F(a)^n = F(na)$$
$$F(n) = e^n$$

Without assuming G(x) = ln(x) or F(x) = e^x.

We also know that 
$$G(ab) = G(a) + G(b)$$
and 
$$G(\frac{1}{x}) = -G(x)$$

I am sorry if these problems are somewhat self-explanatory or bothersome, but I'd love it if you could help me understand! :))

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176741/prove-that-fxy-fx-fy-when-fx-is-not-lnx#comment4477418_2176741 and here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177866/prove-if-fxy-fxfy-then-fx-ax

Comment: Wow, thank you :)) Although one of the links were another question of mine haha

Comment: :P  No problem!  (I'm sure there's other similar questions, but those were the ones I could immediately find.)

Comment: If you have already proven the formulas for $G$, then these follow immediately from $F$ being the inverse function of $G$: $G(F(a + b)) = ?$, and $G(F(a)F(b)) = ?$ Both of these can be answered using the product formula for $G$ and the fact that it is the inverse of $F$.